# Good .NET4 hosting providers

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Are there any good .NET4 Hosting providers that could host an MVC.net 4.0 application.  IXWebhosting which is what I'm using now, says that they have no plans to move to 4.0.  Either virtualized hosting or dedicated depending on the price?

Comment: I've used www.brinkster.com for many sites. They have .NET4 on servers ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.webhostingtalk.com forum, because you can find plenty of offer, review and (it is important) also exclusive discount.

Personally, i visit this site because the review and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of options out there depending on how much you want to spend.  I've had relatively good luck with http://ReliableSite.net (although not specifically with MVC apps).  Support can be a little slow though.

If you want a virtual dedicated machine, check out Rackspace Cloud Servers (http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/).  Little bit more expensive, but highly reliable and can scale as you need it.  You are in full control of your server.

Answer (score 0):

I have happy so far with [DiscountASP](http://discountasp.net/)

Answer (score 0):

M6 Hosting, Bizhostnet and DiscountASP are some of the reliable hosts. Other than that [Hostgator](http://hostgator.com) and [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/) also offer .NET and media hosting. If you choose to got the route of VPS and dedicated hosting then there are many hosts available offering managed .NET hosting.